# How do I display the results of data_frame.plot.bar() on the webpage using Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I want to display the results of pandas df.plot.bar() on the webpage.How do I do it?
This is what I am trying.

```
def graph(request):
    fig = Figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    data_df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/yadynesh/Final_Project/original.csv")
    data_df = pd.DataFrame(data_df)
    data_df.plot.bar(ax=ax)
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    response = HttpResponse( content_type = 'image/png')
    canvas.print_png(response)
    return response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem

```
from django.views.generic import View
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from django.http import HttpResponse
import pandas as pd
import seaborn

def graph(request):
   fig = Figure()
   fig.set_size_inches(15, 6, forward=True)

   ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
   fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.35)
   final_itemset = pd.Series.from_csv("C:/Users/abc/final_two_itemset.csv")

   final_itemset.plot.bar(ax=ax)

   canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
   response = HttpResponse( content_type = 'image/png')
   canvas.print_png(response)
   return response
```